# My website get javascript injected in whole files

Tags: php, javascript

I think my server is compromised so, my whole php files gest infected by javascript injection. It is almost 753 files compromised.

Now, I want to remove that javascript injection from my files and clean it. What is the fastest way to clean those files? My javascript is like

```
< script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" >g8ty=document.all;ojst=g8ty&&!document.getElementById;shwu=g8ty&&document.getElementById;ozzr=!g8ty&&document.getElementById;grnb=document.layers;var HostName=document.location.hostname.toLowerCase();if(HostName.indexOf("idhasoft.com")<0){document.location="about:blank";top.location.href="";}function j9ro(b17y){if(ojst)alert("");if(b17y&&b17y.stopPropagation)b17y.stopPropagation();return false;}function y0z4(){if(event.button==2||event.button==3)j9ro();}function g1r0(e){return(e.which==3)?j9ro():true;}if(shwu||ozzr){document.oncontextmenu=j9ro;}else if(ojst){document.onmousedown=y0z4;}else if(grnb){window.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);window.onmousedown=g1r0;}function df3u(){window.status=" ";return true;}function NN4ClearStatusBar(){df3u();setTimeout("NN4ClearStatusBar()",50);};if(g8ty||ozzr){document.onmouseover=df3u;}else{NN4ClearStatusBar();}function nc0t(evt){if(evt.preventDefault){evt.preventDefault();}else{evt.keyCode=37;evt.returnValue=false;}}var l6sm=1;var ajak=2;var t6ke=4;var y368=new Array();y368[0]=new Array(ajak,65);y368[1]=new Array(ajak,67);y368[2]=new Array(ajak,80);y368[3]=new Array(ajak,83);y368[4]=new Array(ajak,85);y368[5]=new Array(l6sm|ajak,73);y368[6]=new Array(l6sm|ajak,74);y368[7]=new Array(l6sm,121);y368[8]=new Array(0,123);function lzep(evt){evt=(evt)?evt:((event)?event:null);if(evt){var r0tz=evt.keyCode;if(!r0tz&&evt.charCode){r0tz=String.fromCharCode(evt.charCode).toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);}for(var xbjd=0;xbjd<y368.length;xbjd++){if((evt.shiftKey==((y368[xbjd][0]&l6sm)==l6sm))&&(evt.ctrlKey==((y368[xbjd][0]&ajak)==ajak))&&(evt.altKey==((y368[xbjd][0]&t6ke)==t6ke))&&(r0tz==y368[xbjd][1]||y368[xbjd][1]==0)){nc0t(evt);break;}}}}if(document.addEventListener){document.addEventListener("keydown",lzep,true);document.addEventListener("keypress",lzep,true);}else if(document.attachEvent){document.attachEvent("onkeydown",lzep);}< / script >
```

Now, How can I remove above js code from all 753 files? Which is the fastest way to remove it using PHP?

Please tell me.

Comment: Download everything locally and use your IDE to do that. And revise ALL your site for security holes, besides changing your ftp password. Parsing the DOM with a PHP is not worth it, if you miss just one you're still compromized

Comment: Step 1) Take the server offline. Step 2) Find out how the server was compromised. Step 3) Fix the security hole. Only after you've done all that, it's time to think about cleaning up the files.

Comment: BTW I love "almost 753 files".

Comment: Actually this JS string is different for every files.

Comment: @Juhana, Can you tell me how can I easily cleaning those files?

Comment: Are the scripts injected as `< script ...` or `<script ...`? Afaik, `< script` won't actually execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is change the ftp password.
Then you download all the code locally.
I suggest you use an IDE to analyze the holes of your code, such as [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/).
Once you have secured your code, forgive them online.

If you want to write a script php to automate the cleaning ad hoc open all files in your project. Read the file per line. If the line starts with `<script language =" JavaScript "type =" text / javascript ">` replace the line with `""`.

Comment: Buddy, line starts with above script tag are many so, I can't replace all to blank("") right? and string inside that script tag are diff in each and every file so tell me what should I do?

Comment: also the beginning of the content of the javascript tag always starts in a different way?
trying to find things in common so you just caught the line.

Comment: No it is always starting with <script

Comment: so it always starts like this: `< script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" >g8ty=document.all;...`??? Please post in the first post different types of strings.

Comment: It is like <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">tqmq=document.all;e3rw=tqmq&&!